# infinite loop with tf.while_loop supported?

Tags: tensorflow

I intend to write a queue runner thread which does some processing. But basically I can formulate my action as some TF op which depends on another `queue.dequeue`.

So, maybe the canonical way to write this would be:

```
op = make_op()
with coord.stop_on_exception():
  while True:
    session.run(op)
```

At the very end it would stop because of an `OutOfRangeError` exception.

I could however also implement the loop as part of the graph and write it like this:

```
def body(last):
  with tf.control_dependencies([last]):
    return make_op()
op = tf.while_loop(
  cond=lambda: tf.constant(True),
  body=body,
  loop_vars=[tf.no_op()],
  parallel_iterations=1, back_prop=False)
with coord.stop_on_exception():
  session.run(op)
```

I would expect that this is faster because there will be no Python code involved while executing the loop. Is there any downsides with this approach or any reason why this would not work?